# Bootstrap 3 Carousel with buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap 3 and working on a Carousel for my website.
I need to create a carousel with "fade" effect and 4 buttons below the carousel which when clicked trigger the transition between images. I don't want to use the default controls provided by the bootstrap API (left/right arrows and indicators).

I want to create something like this - 
https://moodle.org/

Here's my code so far -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body style="padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px;">
<div id="myCarousel" data-interval="false" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >     

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
      <img  alt="First slide" src="1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img  alt="Second slide" src="1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img alt="Third slide" src="1.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

</div><!-- /.carousel -->

<div align="center">
  <p>Carousel with auto-slide disabled!</p>
</div>



  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer>
    <p class="pull-right"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>© 2014 Company, Inc. · <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#">Privacy</a> · <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>

</div><!-- /.container -->




<script src="./Carousel Template for Bootstrap_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Carousel Template for Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Carousel Template for Bootstrap_files/docs.min.js"></script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: I would go with a different slider if you need more controls. Bootstrap carousel seems pretty limited.

Comment: What exactly, is your question?

Comment: you might be interested in this: http://wowslider.com/html5-image-slider-box-stack-v-demo.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this with Bootstrap..

http://bootply.com/113737

It uses the `data-target` and `data-slide-to` navigate to specific slide.

Comment: Nice example .... but the buttons below do not scale properly when the screen size is adjusted.. What can be done to fix this ? So that the buttons appear right below the carousel no matter what the screen size.....